# printing * in respective number using printf in C

Tags: c, printf

I'm trying to work on this assignment that prints "*" in their respective number.  Also, if you see the picture I need to display the min and the max number, how can I do this?  I was thinking about doing it with an array storing those numbers there but when I created the array and tried to pass them I got an error.

Here's the picture:
[image: Output Example]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>

int f(int);

int main(void){
    int i, t, funval,tempL,tempH;
        int a;


    // Make sure to change low and high when testing your program
    int low=-3, high=11;
    for (t=low; t<=high;t++){
        printf("f(%2d)=%3d\n",t,f(t));

        }

    printf("\n");
    printf("   ");
    for (i=1; i<=31; i+=5)
        printf("%3d   ", i);
        printf("\n");
        printf("   ");
    for (i=1; i<=31; i+=5)
        printf("  |   ");
        printf("\n");


    for (t=low; t<=high;t++){
        printf("t=%2d\n",t);

    }
    printf("\n");
   for(i=0;i<=sizeof(nums)/sizeof(int);i++){
    if (nums[i] > max)
        {
      max = nums[i];
        }
   if (nums[i] < min)
        {
      min = nums[i];
        }
    }
    printf("Min: %d\n", min);
    printf("Max: %d\n", max);

    printf("\n");
    printf("   ");
    for (i=min; i<=max; i+=5)
        printf("%3d   ", i);
        printf("\n");
        printf("   ");
    for (i=min; i<=max; i+=5)
        printf("  |   ");
        printf("\n");


    for (t=low; t<=high;t++){
    printf("t=%2d\n",t);

    }

    // Your code here...
    return 0;
}


int f(int t){
    // example 1
    return (t*t-4*t+5);

    // example 2
    // return (-t*t+4*t-1);

    // example 3
    // return (sin(t)*10);

    // example 4
    // if (t>0)
    //  return t*2;
    // else
    //  return t*8;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please don't post so many comments in your `f()`, for example.  For min and max, how would you determine the min and max values on paper? (Check each value, keeping a track of the current min and max and compare the new value with the old extrema.)  ou're going to juggle some of the hard-coded numbers in the existing code. AFAICS, you'll need to change the last loop shown and put some of your code in there (rather than after it). But really, you should be showing us what you've tried, rather than hoping for us to do it for you — we don't do homework, but we do help.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I said I know how to do the min and max when they are store in an array,I never said write the code for it....

Comment: OK; then I'm not sure what your question is.  You've not shown your code that attempts to use an array, so we can't help you debug whatever problem you had with it.

Comment: Neither the code or the picture match the problem described, which is ultimately `array storing those numbers there but when I created the array and tried to pass them I got an error.`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for letting me know the rules of the forum!,I will show you guys my work

Comment: Please update the question so that the code can be formatted for readability.  Then delete your comment.  (I'll delete this one too.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int parabola1(int);

int *calc(int low, int high, int (*f)(int), int *size, int *min, int *max){
/*
#input
low, high : range {x| low <= x <= high}
f : function
#output
*size : Size of array
*min : Minimum value of f(x)
*max : Maximum value
return : pointer to first element of int num[*size]
         NULL if this can not be ensured.
*/
    int i, x, *nums;
    *size = high - low + 1;
    *max = *min = f(low);//value of the provisional
    if(NULL==(nums=malloc(*size*sizeof(*nums)))){
        return NULL;//max and min are unavailable
    }
    for(i = 0, x = low; x <= high; ++x, ++i){
        nums[i] = f(x);
        if(nums[i] > *max)
            *max = nums[i];
        if(nums[i] < *min)
            *min = nums[i];
    }
    return nums;
}

int main(void){
    int i, t;
    int *nums, size;
    int low=-3, high=9, min, max;

    nums = calc(low, high, parabola1, &size, &min, &max);
    for (i=0; i<size;i++){
        printf("f(%2d)=%3d\n", low+i, nums[i]);
    }
    printf("--\n");
    printf("min=%3d\n", min);
    printf("max=%3d\n", max);
    printf("--\n");

    t = -2;
    printf("t=%2d%*s%c\n", t, nums[t-low]-min, "", '*');
    free(nums);
    return 0;
}

int parabola1(int t){
    return t*(t-4)+5;
}
```