# Plotting with C

Tags: c

I am working on a program plot.c to plot a function f(t). I can't use nested For loops unfortunately which make this harder for me.For example a function like : `f(t)=t^2-4t+5`.

The values of t will be between two values specified as low and high in the program. For each value of t, i want to store an asterisk in the element of a string (i.e. an array of chars) corresponding to the function value f(t), while all leading elements before the asterisk are blank.

This is of course assuming that the f(t) values are rounded to integers.In terms of the array in C, its size could be a variable. For instance:

```
int m=3*6; 
char ex[m];
```

Here is what the outputs are supposed to look like :

[image]

[image]

Comment: You pushed the "Ask Question" button, but then you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25614386/971127

Comment: Sorry guys, the reason it was blank is because I have to edit it.

Comment: You don't show any code, so we cannot help you.

Comment: BLUEPIXY, the answer for that problem does not fit my situation. the program needs to plot any function, not just a parabola

Comment: Can you use `goto`-s? If you can, mimic `for` loops with them.

Answer (score 3):

If you have integer values, you could abuse `printf` format specifications.

If you want to print a * preceeded by n spaces, you could use something like:

```
printf("%*s\n", n, "*");
```

Bear in mind tha tif this is for a class assignment, you also need to be able to explain why this works, but the relevant section should be in the man page for `printf`.

Comment: So i am still kind of confused by that. I managed to code the top part which is the y axis but i can't do the x axis. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well..., you're trying to print a line that should have a number (the value of x for that line). The part I showed you should be trivially adaptable to take more things to print out (by adjusting the format string and the arguments passed). Look at, say, the docs for the `%d` format character.